# How to have a button in tkinter refresh page and re-call random.choice?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've looked at many questions and answers already:

- [[1] Refresh a tkinter frame on button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45064732/refresh-a-tkinter-frame-on-button-press)
- [[2] Is there a way to refresh a frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832722/is-there-a-way-to-refresh-a-frame)
- [[3] Does Tkinter have a refresh method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477636/does-tkinter-have-a-refresh-method/19477781#19477781)
- [[4] How to refresh the window in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997347/how-to-refresh-the-window-in-tkinter?rq=1)

None have the necessary info or are able to answer my question.

Here is a class in my app. This window is called when the user presses the "Mexican" button as a food choice on the previous page. On this page the user is presented with 3 options,

1. YES - user likes the restaurant choice and the app quits
2. TRY AGAIN - the user still wants Mexican food but not the choice
   given
3. I Don't Want Mexican Anymore - self-explanatory, and goes back to
   choice of type of restaurant

My question refers to the TRY AGAIN option. I've tried Tk.update, creating a refresh function, lamba function calls, like `command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MexicanRest)` but nothing refreshes the current page and allows for the `mex_choice = random.choice(mexican_rest)` command to be called again and pick a new restaurant from the `mexican_rest` list defined.

You'll see where I've marked the `#WHAT GOES HERE TO REFRESH?" 
Please advise...

```
class MexicanRest(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Mexican Restaurant", 
                        font=('century gothic', 24))
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        mex_choice = random.choice(mexican_rest)

        label = tk.Label(self, 
                        text="How does %s sound? " %mex_choice, 
                        bg='yellow', 
                        font=('times', 24), 
                        fg='red')
        label.pack()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, 
                        text='YES', 
                        width=20, 
                        command=quit)
        button1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, 
                        text='TRY AGAIN', 
                        width=20, 
                        command=self.refresh) #WHAT GOES HERE TO REFRESH???
        button2.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

        button3 = tk.Button(self, 
                        text='I Don\'t Want Mexican Anymore', 
                        #width=20, 
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button3.pack(fill=tk.BOTH)

    def refresh(self):
        MexicanRest.update(self)
```

Comment: tkinter can't automagically update windows. You have to write the code to do that.

Comment: @BryanOakley Then what can I add into the refresh() method to update the window? +1 for "automagically" - I like that and will be using it from now on.

Comment: Are you aware that all widgets have multiple methods for setting and clearing the values displayed in the widgets? You just need to call those methods on the widgets you want to be updated.

Comment: @BryanOakley That doesn't help at all. Example please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. Make it so that it's possible to access the widgets that should be refreshed (eg: make them instance attributes)
2. Write a function to reconfigure those widgets

In your case, the first step is to create an attribute for the label you want to refresh. For example:

```
self.choice_label = tk.Label(self, 
                text="How does %s sound? " %mex_choice, 
                bg='yellow', 
                font=('times', 24), 
                fg='red')
self.choice_label.pack()
```

Next, create a function that updates that label:

```
def refresh(self):
    mex_choice = random.choice(mexican_rest)
    self.choice_label.configure(text="How does %s sound? " %mex_choice)
```

Comment: You're brilliant! Thank you!